# Curve_Fit Cannot find Covariance of First Order System

Tags: scipy, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a simple model in the form of y = A(1-exp(-t/tau))+A0 yet curve_fit spits out the error

```
Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated
```

and gives me an atrocious fit. Are my default parameters not robust enough?

Here is my code and data:

```
    Time (s)    Ads 1   Ads 2   Ads 3   Des 1   Des 2   Des 3   Des 4
0   0   18.979  18.979  18.979  19.034  19.042  19.026  19.028
1   30  18.997  18.993  18.993  19.023  19.019  19.015  NaN
2   45  19.004  18.997  19.000  19.021  19.018  19.012  NaN
3   60  19.009  19.003  19.007  19.020  19.012  19.012  19.011
4   75  19.013  19.007  19.012  19.019  19.011  19.010  19.009
5   90  19.016  19.010  19.015  19.018  19.009  19.009  19.008
6   300 19.022  19.022  19.028  NaN 18.990  18.989  18.990
7   600 NaN NaN NaN NaN 18.984  NaN NaN
```

```
time = df['Time (s)']
def first_order(t,A,tau=100,A0=1):
    t0 = t[0]
    y = A*(1-np.exp(-(t-t0)/tau))+A0
    return y
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(first_order, time, df["Des 2"])
plt.plot(time,df["Des 2"])
plt.plot(np.linspace(time[0],time[-1:],100),first_order(np.linspace(time[0],time[-1:],100),*parameters),'--')
```

[image: Result of Data and Fit]

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a suitable initial guess for the parameters (`p0`).

Below the code and the image of the fitted model:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

time = [0, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90, 300, 600]
des2 = [19.042, 19.019, 19.018, 19.012, 19.011, 19.009, 18.990, 18.984]


def first_order(t, A, tau, A0):
    t0 = t[0]
    y = - (A * (1 - np.exp(-(t - t0) / tau)) + A0)
    return y


parameters, _ = curve_fit(first_order, time, des2, p0=(1, 100, 1))
plt.plot(time, des2)
plt.plot(
    np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100),
    first_order(np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100), *parameters),
    "--",
)
plt.show()
```

[image]